# How To read XML 'local file' and Parsing in Cocoa Touch

Tags: xml, cocoa-touch, resources, nsxmlparser

I can read **remote** XML with the following code:

```
-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:urlString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];       

    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}
```

And I'm calling the above function here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    xmlcont = [[XMLController alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://192.168.10.12:81/book.xml"];

    for (Tweet *t in [xmlcont tweets]) {
        NSLog(@"At date: %@ you wrote: %@",[t createdAt], [t content]);
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Actually I'd like to do something like this, little as one difference. I want to read a XML **local file** that is in my **resource folder** on my Project in XCode, but definitelly I don't know how to do this! I'm getting crazy with that! I'm just can to read XML remote file (http://..../file.xml).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say there is a `file.xml` in your resources folder that you want to parse. You can get the file path like this,

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"xml"];
```

There are two ways you can use this to get what you want.

**Using file URL**

```
NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    ....
```

**Using file data**

```
NSData * fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:fileData];
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for complete examples. It's so easy, but there are few examples so much explained as yours. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jbernardo If this answer solved your problem you should accept it, to give the answerer some well-earned credit :-)